# create multiple .lsf files with same content but replaceable IDs

Tags: r

I have a 001.lsf file for subject 001 as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -J T2_001  # name for the job

export SUBJECTS_DIR=/subjects/001
cd $SUBJECTS_DIR
mri_convert -in 001 -out 001_2 -U 300
```

I would like to use R to substitute 001 with a list of subjects 002, 003, 004, ...etc. and generate .lsf files with that subject's name

I have a general idea of generating a loop, Can everyone help with the rest of the loop?

```
list=c(002, 003, 004...etc)
for i in length(list)
{
  df<- read.table("001.lsf")
}
```

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both could be improved a little by doing checks for file-clobbering, i.e., don't over-write an existing file. It sounds like this is a one-time task, so perhaps this isn't critical this time.

## Bash

```sh
for i in 002 003 004 ; do
  sed -e "s/\b001\b/${i}/g" < 001.lsf > "${i}.lsf"
done
```

## R

```r
txt1 <- readLines("001.lsf")
for (i in c("002", "003", "004")) {
  writeLines(gsub("\\b001\\b", i, txt1), paste0(i, ".lsf"))
}
```

---

BTW, in the event your `for` code is *not* intended to be pseudo-code, then:

- you are missing parens, in R `for` loops are always:

  ```r
  for (i in some_list) { ... }
  ```
- `i in length(list)` will always iterate exactly once: if the list is empty, then it will iterate with `i=0`; if the list has 1000 elements, then it will iterate once with `i=1000`. Perhaps you meant:

  ```r
  for (i in seq_along(list)) { ... }
  ```
- in case you were thinking it and didn't notice in the previous bullet, one might be tempted to use `for (i in 1:length(list))`, but see what happens when your `list` variable is *empty*: it resolves into `for (i in 1:0)` which actually loops *twice*, since `1:0` resolves into `[1] 1 0`, not an empty vector. That's why I used `seq_along` (and similarly `seq_len`), since it returns `integer(0)` when its argument is empty ... and this causes the `for` loop to *not* iterate.
- Lastly, `list` is technically fine, but re-using function names for variables can be problematic, both in how they perform and what types of errors you get. In this case, if you don't define your vector, `length(list)` still works without warning or error, because its argument is a function and therefore is of length 1 ... not what you intend. In different circumstances (such as `$`, `[`, etc), you might get an error such as

  ```
  Error: object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
  ## or
  Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
  ```

  which is *much* less intuitive than what you might expect

  ```
  Error: object 'quux' not found
  ```

  which clearly indicates that you have not defined your variable.

  Both of these issues are avoided if you use an otherwise non-existent name for your variable, such as `list_of_ids` or `listOfIds` or `quux`, depending on your preference for naming convention and name-obscurity.

Comment: Thank you! It works with creating name of the files. However, R script have a problem applying the changes of job name: T1_001 to T1_002 and output: 001_2 to 002_2, which with extra prefix '_' and postfix '_'.  Should I make changes to gsub("\\b129_S_4371\\b",1,txt1)? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know that I follow the problem, zenoZeng ...

Comment: Following your R script, SUBJECTS_DIR=/subjects/001 was successfully convert to subjects/002, subjects/003, etc. However, the 'BSUB -J T2_001' and 'mri_convert -out 001_2' with prefix of 'T2_' and suffix '_2' of 001 was not converted as expected.